# Poll for all threads to return expected result using java8

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I want to call different servers with multithreads

and poll till all servers return the expected value (a new value that should be updated on all servers. Till it's updated it returns `oldValue`).

Is there any best-practice to do so in java 8?

Any fork and wait. ThreadsPoolExectuor with tasks that have polling in their body?

I thought to do polling on this code,

which mean i will also re-try servers which already brought the new expected value:

```
        long instancesWithNewVersion = managedInstances.parallelStream()
                .map(item -> pollTillGetNewVersion(item))
                .filter( version -> version.equals(expectedVersion))
                .count();
```

//                    .reduce(new StringBuilder(), accumulator, (left, right) -> left.append(right));

but it can be more efficient if the polling is done only on the instances that didn't return the expected string answer

Comment: Why would you use that code instead of an `Executor`?

Comment: I understood that he wants to poll the servers until they reply what he wants like some sort of cyber bullying (or polling), but this whole question is quite unclear.

Comment: I hope i made it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stream API is not designed for such tasks, it’s intended for computation task, i.e. tasks which consume CPU time, not tasks waiting for a server response.

Using an `ExecutorService` is straight-forward if you formulate the tasks as waiting for a particular server’s state, rather than trying to formulate a “poll all servers” action. E.g.

```
ExecutorService es=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Math.min(managedInstances.size(), 100));
es.invokeAll(managedInstances.stream()
    .<Callable<Void>>map(item -> () -> {
        while(!getVersion(item).equals(expectedVersion)) Thread.sleep(5000);
        return null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
es.shutdown();
```

The thread limit of `100` has been chosen arbitrarily, usually, you want to use a number significantly higher than the number of CPUs as most tasks will be sleeping or waiting for the server at a particular point of time. For most practical tasks, the total number of waiting or sleeping threads does not affect the system’s performance, so you could even use an unbounded `newCachedThreadPool()`, though most developers sleep better when they know, they have capped the maximum thread count.

The wait time of `5000`ms also has been chosen arbitrarily. Keep in mind that this is the time the action waits before polling the *same* server again and there should be a policy of not polling the same server too fast. The different servers still are being queried simultaneously.

When `invokeAll` returns, all servers have already responded they way you wish. In principle, the `ExecutorService` can be reused for other tasks before being shut down.

Comment: thanks. What will it be bad if I use the parallel stream for calling the polling the servers?

Comment: The parallel stream implementation will split the workload between a number of threads matching the number of CPU cores. These threads will then be blocked by waiting for as much servers as you have CPU cores, instead of using the free CPU time for sending more requests to other servers. Even worse, this would impact other, really computational parallel stream operations running at the same time, which *could* utilize the CPU, if the threads weren’t blocked by waiting for servers.

Comment: sorry for asking again regarding your last comment, but: 1) I can set System property so the parallelStream would use more threads than cores. 2)I can put the polling inside the `"map"` function. With those two- there is still advantage for Executors.newFixedThreadPool?

Comment: Since the Stream implementation uses the default Fork/Join pool, you can configure it’s target concurrency via `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` property, however, writing code relying on such an implementation specific behavior can not be considered correct Java code. Also, configuring this has an impact on all Stream operations and also other parallel features of the JRE. Now ask the other way round, what do you think, is the advantage of using a Stream for this at all costs?